# How can I get python symlink files from an RPM package?

Tags: python-3.x, rpm, site-packages

I have the following code which gets all RPM packages and then extracts all files within these RPM packages.

However this does not list .py files which are symlinks,

How can I include symlink files in my search ?
Can I update rpm command or is there an alternative ?

```
def run_command( self, command ):
      result = subprocess.run( command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, check=True )
      if result.returncode != 0:
         raise subprocess.CalledProcessError( result.returncode, command,
                result.stderr )

      return result.stdout

def getRPMFiles( self ):
      rpmFiles = []

      # Get a list of all installed RPM packages
      rpmPackagesList = self.run_command( "rpm -qa" ).splitlines()

      allFiles = {}
      for package in rpmPackagesList:
         filesList = self.run_command( f"rpm -ql { package }" ).splitlines()
         allFiles[ package ] = filesList
     
      # Iteration logic to add items to rpmFiles variable

      return rpmFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. If the symlink is created in a scriptlet, then it is not owned by the package, and there is no way to get this info from rpmdb.

By the way - you can query the rpm using the Python library. See https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/query-rpm-database-python